# Python Selenium .send_keys() doesn't work after element changes class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to input the name of the city that I want to depart from into Google Flights using python. After locating the element (the input box) in the html code I noticed that once you interact with the element it changes its class from `class="II2One j0Ppje zmMKJ LbIaRd"` to `class="II2One j0Ppje zmMKJ LbIaRd VfPpkd-ksKsZd-mWPk3d-OWXEXe-AHe6Kc-XpnDCe"`. Therefore `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.LbIaRd').send_keys(city_name)` only manages to send the first character of the string before the input box changes class. However I am unable to send any text to this element after it changes its class.

I have tried interacting with the element in order to change its class and then applying the same method to the new class of the input box:

```
x = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.LbIaRd')[0]
x.click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.VfPpkd-ksKsZd-mWPk3d-OWXEXe-AHe6Kc-XpnDCe').send_keys(city_name)
```

The code ends with no errors but it the text is not sent to the input box. There is only one element with `.VfPpkd-ksKsZd-mWPk3d-OWXEXe-AHe6Kc-XpnDCe` locator.

I have also tried to click the element after the class change and then send the keys:

```
x = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.LbIaRd')[0]
x.click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.VfPpkd-ksKsZd-mWPk3d-OWXEXe-AHe6Kc-XpnDCe').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.VfPpkd-ksKsZd-mWPk3d-OWXEXe-AHe6Kc-XpnDCe').send_keys(city_name)
```

But I get the following exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
Message: element click intercepted:
Element <input class="II2One j0Ppje zmMKJ LbIaRd VfPpkd-ksKsZd-mWPk3d-OWXEXe-AHe6Kc-XpnDCe, redacted html code">
is not clickable at point (612, 472).
Other element would receive the click: <input class="II2One j0Ppje zmMKJ LbIaRd", redacted html code>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the page you want to use?

Comment: this may be because the element changes after clicking the element (for example, its class can be added active). Are you sure that `CSS_SELECTOR` can select the same element after clicking?

Comment: @AomineDaici   The element's class changes after the initial click . The problem for me is that this change happens so quickly that element.send_keys() can't send keys in time and for some reason is unable to send them to this element after the class change even after I update the CSS_SELECTOR to match the new class. What do you mean by 'class can be added active'?

Comment: @JakyRuby  it's https://www.google.com/travel/flights and the element I'm trying to access is the search bar on the front page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Try to send keys with ActionChains instead with send_keys function

```
# Needed libs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

# We create the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# We instantiate the ActionChains which will allow to us to send several keys
action = ActionChains(driver)

# We maximize the window
driver.maximize_window()

# We navigate to the url
url='https://www.google.com/travel/flights'
driver.get(url)

departure = "Berlin, Germany"
destiny = "Austin, Texas, USA"
# We click on Reject cookies button from pop up
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//button)[1]"))).click()

# We clear the departure input in case there is something
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//input)[1]"))).clear()
# We click on it
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//input)[1]"))).click()
# We send the keys with the actionChains previously initialized
action.send_keys(departure).perform()
# We click on the first result
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//ul[@role='listbox']//div[text()='{departure}']"))).click()

# Same for destiny input
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//input)[3]"))).click()
action.send_keys(destiny).perform()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//ul[@role='listbox']//div[text()='{destiny}']"))).click()

# Click on search button
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//button/span[text()='Search']"))).click()
```

Comment: thank you, it worked excellently. I didn't even know there was such a thing as ActionChains :)